# Is there a way to use Azure Logic Apps or Azure Function to grab Office365 IPs and convert them into Azure Firewall ruleset?

Tags: networking, azure-functions, office365, azure-logic-apps

I want to know if there is a way to use Azure Logic Apps or Azure Function to do the following;

1. Scrape content from

> https://endpoints.office.com/endpoints/worldwide?clientrequestid=b10c5ed1-bad1-445f-b386-b919946339a7

2. Filter to only IPv4 addresses and strip out all the rest
3. Use that list of IPv4 addresses and save somewhere as a .CSV file
4. Use that .CSV file and upload it to an IP-Group in Azure
5. Use the IP-GROUP and apply it to an Azure Firewall rule

Reason; this way, the dynamically changing list of MS O365 IP addresses will be dynamically updated every 15 days so that the Azure Firewall Ruleset is updated automatically too.

Comment: The simple answer is yes, you just need to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use [this](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Network-Security/tree/00d155a0255ed3da7749a96a7cdcc44a0f22b12b/Azure%20Firewall/Template%20-%20Logic%20App%20and%20Automation%20Account%20for%20Adding%20O365%20Rules%20to%20Azure%20Firewall) as inspiration.

I recently created a PowerShell script that parses the endpoint information and outputs it into terraform files. A pipeline runs the script monthly then runs the terraform apply.